# How to display date time field based on local time zone using Noda time c#

Tags: c#, nodatime

I have tried using the below code but it didnt work

```
Instant instant = Instant.FromDateTimeUtc(DateTime.Now);
IDateTimeZoneProvider timeZoneProvider = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb;
var usersTimezone = timeZoneProvider[Request.Cookies["ahcs"]["timeZone"].ToString()];
var usersZonedDateTime = instant.InZone(usersTimezone);
```

Comment: I think, if I'm not wrong it be default takes the local time zone.

Comment: I have two dropdowns one contains country list and another the time zones associated to thay country.based on the country and timezone user selects the datetime fields needs to be converted into that timezone

Comment: This looks reasonable on the face of it (though I'm not sure why you need to call `.ToString()` on the cookie value), assuming that your cookie is being populated with a TZDB timezone somehow.  What didn't work: do you get an error, or the wrong result?  Please add more information to the question.

Comment: i have got it working now but i have a question here is there any way to find out culture info based on time zone ?

Comment: @Yogesh: No, because there's no necessary correlation. I could be a French person in America, for example. Also, `Instant.FromDateTimeUtc(DateTime.Now)` is broken - either use `DateTime.UtcNow`, or (preferrably) use `IClock`, e.g. via `SystemClock.Instance`. That's what it's there for.

Comment: @Yogesh - "it didn't work" is not very helpful.  [Please read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Also, how are we to know what value is being returned by that cookie?  You should provide an example.  Please edit your question accordingly.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
TimeZoneInfo timeZonetoConvert = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(TimeZoneId2);
    DateTime newTime = new DateTime();

    TimeZoneInfo timeZonefromConvert = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(TimeZoneId2);
    newTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTimeToConvert, timeZonefromConvert, timeZonetoConvert );
```